# how to merge two files based on single column

Tags: text-processing, join

I would like to merge two files. I looked upon the previous questions and answers but none of them matches my desired output. 
There are two csv files - file1.csv, file2.csv. file1.csv and file2.csv are not of same length. the program should merge both the files and printing everything from both file based on column 1 
 
Input

file1.csv has 4 columns.

```
$ cat file1.csv
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1 [1169 - 963] (REVERSE SENSE),MQGHRRKLATPRQRAPRKERQRALLLRLQWRIGLQPCSRRNKSLDRKNIYWRYLVEYGSWKGRTHISDV,C# 
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_7_3,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_17965_1 [90 - 278],MADVEKTSCCTETKECCKDETCCENGQGACHTGKEECKDTCHKKACGCKAGEDCKCSDGKCGC,CC#CC#CC#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C# 

$ cat file2.csv
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1, SignalP-4.1,     SIGNAL,  1,    22, 0.808,  YES
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_8_2, SignalP-4.1,    SIGNAL  1,  20, 0.877,  YES
```

Output

```
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1 [1169 - 963] (REVERSE SENSE),MQGHRRKLATPRQRAPRKERQRALLLRLQWRIGLQPCSRRNKSLDRKNIYWRYLVEYGSWKGRTHISDV,C#,Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1, SignalP-4.1,     SIGNAL,  1,   22, 0.808,  YES
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_7_3,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_17965_1 [90 - 278],MADVEKTSCCTETKECCKDETCCENGQGACHTGKEECKDTCHKKACGCKAGEDCKCSDGKCGC,CC#CC#CC#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#,no match
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: _...printing everything from both files based on column 1_ Your desired output contains only lines from file1.csv

Comment: what about line in file 2 missing from file 1 e.g. Contig_Spider_Gland_98_8_2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
join -t, file1.csv file2.csv -a 1 -o auto -e 'no match'
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1 [1169 - 963] (REVERSE SENSE),MQGHRRKLATPRQRAPRKERQRALLLRLQWRIGLQPCSRRNKSLDRKNIYWRYLVEYGSWKGRTHISDV,C# , SignalP-4.1,     SIGNAL,  1,    22, 0.808,  YES
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_7_3,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_17965_1 [90 - 278],MADVEKTSCCTETKECCKDETCCENGQGACHTGKEECKDTCHKKACGCKAGEDCKCSDGKCGC,CC#CC#CC#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C# ,no match,no match,no match,no match,no match,no match
```

And if the lines form file2 need to be printed as well:

```
join -t, file1.csv file2.csv -a 1 -a2 -o auto -e 'no match'
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1 [1169 - 963] (REVERSE SENSE),MQGHRRKLATPRQRAPRKERQRALLLRLQWRIGLQPCSRRNKSLDRKNIYWRYLVEYGSWKGRTHISDV,C# , SignalP-4.1,     SIGNAL,  1,    22, 0.808,  YES
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_7_3,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_17965_1 [90 - 278],MADVEKTSCCTETKECCKDETCCENGQGACHTGKEECKDTCHKKACGCKAGEDCKCSDGKCGC,CC#CC#CC#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C# ,no match,no match,no match,no match,no match,no match
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_8_2,no match,no match,no match, SignalP-4.1,    SIGNAL  1,  20, 0.877,  YES,no match
```